# TelerikUI for iOS: linking fails: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

I want to use the TelerikUI framework in my project.

But when I include it in -->Build Phases --> Link Binaries with libraries, building the project fails with `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I have tried including libsqlite3.dylib but then I get a duplicate symbols error.

Here is the complete log:

> Ld /Users/michi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MedSafe-eeygshuvxxscziftuaslwcjyzejc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MedSafeStatic.app/MedSafeStatic normal i386
>       cd /Users/michi/Documents/MedSafe
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/michi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MedSafe-eeygshuvxxscziftuaslwcjyzejc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/michi/Documents/MedSafe -L/Users/michi/Downloads/CorePlot_1.5.1/Binaries/iOS -L/Users/michi/Downloads/CorePlot_1.5.1/Source/build/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/michi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MedSafe-eeygshuvxxscziftuaslwcjyzejc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/michi/Documents/MedSafe -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/michi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MedSafe-eeygshuvxxscziftuaslwcjyzejc/Build/Intermediates/MedSafe.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MedSafe.build/Objects-normal/i386/MedSafeStatic.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -all_load -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/michi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MedSafe-eeygshuvxxscziftuaslwcjyzejc/Build/Intermediates/MedSafe.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MedSafe.build/MedSafeStatic.xcent -framework TelerikUI -framework Social -framework Accounts -framework Twitter -framework SystemConfiguration -framework StoreKit -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework MobileCoreServices -lz -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework AudioToolbox -framework MessageUI -framework AddressBookUI -framework AddressBook -lCorePlot-CocoaTouch -framework EventKitUI -framework EventKit -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreAudio -framework MapKit -framework Accelerate -framework Parse -framework FacebookSDK -framework CoreData -framework Ensembles -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/michi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MedSafe-eeygshuvxxscziftuaslwcjyzejc/Build/Intermediates/MedSafe.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MedSafe.build/Objects-normal/i386/MedSafeStatic_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/michi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MedSafe-eeygshuvxxscziftuaslwcjyzejc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MedSafeStatic.app/MedSafeStatic
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/michi/Downloads/CorePlot_1.5.1/Source/build/Debug-iphoneos'
>   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider bindObject:toPos:ofStatement:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbdfl_sqlite3_bind_double)
>     "_sqlite3_bind_int", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider bindObject:toPos:ofStatement:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbdfl_sqlite3_bind_int)
>     "_sqlite3_bind_int64", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider bindObject:toPos:ofStatement:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>     "_sqlite3_bind_null", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider bindObject:toPos:ofStatement:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>     "_sqlite3_bind_parameter_count", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider executeUpdateOfData:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>     "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider bindObject:toPos:ofStatement:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbdfl_sqlite3_bind_text)
>     "_sqlite3_changes", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider executeUpdateOfData:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider executeDeleteOfData:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>     "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider deinitializeConnection:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbdfl_sqlite3_close)
>     "_sqlite3_column_count", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider readDataImplWithStatement:parameters:fromTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>     "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider readDataImplWithStatement:parameters:fromTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbdfl_sqlite3_column_double)
>     "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider updateIndicesSchemaForTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider readDataImplWithStatement:parameters:fromTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbdfl_sqlite3_column_int)
>     "_sqlite3_column_int64", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider readDataImplWithStatement:parameters:fromTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>     "_sqlite3_column_name", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider readDataImplWithStatement:parameters:fromTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>     "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider updateSchemaForTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider updateIndicesSchemaForTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider readDataImplWithStatement:parameters:fromTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbdfl_sqlite3_column_text)
>     "_sqlite3_column_text16", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider updateIndicesSchemaForTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>     "_sqlite3_column_type", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider readDataImplWithStatement:parameters:fromTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>     "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider generateResultInfoWithErrorCode:errorText:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbdfl_sqlite3_errmsg)
>     "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider executeNonQuery:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbdfl_sqlite3_exec)
>     "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider updateSchemaForTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider updateIndicesSchemaForTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider executeInsertOfData:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider executeUpdateOfData:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider executeDeleteOfData:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider bindObject:toPos:ofStatement:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider readDataImplWithStatement:parameters:fromTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         ...
>        (maybe you meant: _fbdfl_sqlite3_finalize)
>     "_sqlite3_last_insert_rowid", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider executeInsertOfData:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>     "_sqlite3_open_v2", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider initializeConnection] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>        (maybe you meant: _fbdfl_sqlite3_open_v2)
>     "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider updateSchemaForTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider updateIndicesSchemaForTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider executeInsertOfData:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider executeUpdateOfData:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider executeDeleteOfData:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider readDataImplWithStatement:parameters:fromTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider checkIndexWithName:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         ...
>        (maybe you meant: _fbdfl_sqlite3_prepare_v2)
>     "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider updateSchemaForTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider updateIndicesSchemaForTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider executeInsertOfData:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider executeUpdateOfData:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider executeDeleteOfData:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider readDataImplWithStatement:parameters:fromTable:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         -[TKSQLiteDBProvider checkIndexWithName:] in TelerikUI(TKSQLiteDBProvider.o)
>         ...
>        (maybe you meant: _fbdfl_sqlite3_step)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the sqlite3 framework? Right click on Frameworks, click “Add\Existing Frameworks…”, and select “libsqlite3.dylib” from the dropdown. Or go to build phases - link binary with libraries - press + and search for  “libsqlite3.dylib”